# Toggle feature flag based on client request

Tags: java

I am relatively new to feature flags, Trying to implement feature flag in a REST service which is accessed from 2 client urls. The feature flag should toggle based on the request coming from different clients.

```
if (url1){
  //do old functionality
}else{
  //do new functionality
}
```

Can someone tel me how this can be achieved?

Comment: yeah, you are on the right path, what problem you are facing with above solution ?

Comment: is there any way to check which url the request is coming from and how do i set this in launchdarkly dashboard, as it would temporary. As this is not based on users who login but 2 different urls.

Comment: not sure what is `launchdarkly` you are talking about? You should have access to URL. Better if you can show in a simple controller.

Comment: Its a sdk that helps in feature-flag-driven-development. I am using it to achieve the same. It has a dashboard that helps create the flags and toggle it.

Answer (score 6):

There are many complete solutions for this problem out there. For example some of them:

- [ConfigCat](https://configcat.com/)
- [LaunchDarkly](https://launchdarkly.com/)
- [Unleash](https://www.unleash-hosted.com/)

This is an example how you can use it in java from [here](https://github.com/configcat/java-sdk):

```
ConfigCatClient client = new ConfigCatClient("#YOUR-API-KEY#");

boolean isFeatureEnabled = client.getValue(Boolean.class, "isFeatureEnabled", false);

if (isFeatureEnabled) {
    doTheNewThing();
} else {
    doTheOldThing();
}
```

Usually you can create an account on the regarding website and can generate an `API_KEY` you can use in your clients.

Answer (score 0):

I’m not sure if this will still be relevant to you six months later, but hopefully, it helps someone.

Rollout.io has a series across tech stacks that is a complete beginners introduction to feature flags.
Here’s the Java one, since this is a Java question: [Feature Flags Java Guide](https://rollout.io/resource/java-feature-flags-guide/)  It walks you through the very basics, the theory behind the approach, and using feature flag management solutions if you’re interested in a more comprehensive solution.

Disclosure: I work for Rollout.io